# Keyboard issue with Java Console App in rc.local

Tags: java, console, keyboard, debian-jessie

I am trying to run a java console app in Raspbian rc.local.

It is a boot menu to select a menu item based on a keyboard input.
The program runs fine, if running at command prompt.

However, when starting the java console app within rc.local

```
java -jar /home/pi/RaspPiStartup/RaspPiStartup.jar
```

the application is not able to read keyboard inputs.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Console con=System.console();
    AtomicInteger num=new AtomicInteger(-1);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int i1;
                if (con==null) {
                    System.out.println("KeyScan In");
                    i1=in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("KeyScan "+i1);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("KeyCon In");
                    i1=Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());
                    System.out.println("KeyCon "+i1);
                }
                num.set(i1 );
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Fehler Keyboard In"+e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

I tried several ways, as you see. 
This solution gives me an Exception. 
As con == null in rc.local, the scanner tries to read.
Thus resulting in an java.util.NoSuchElementException.

What do I need to do, to read a keyboard input in rc.local?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1. NoSuchElementException is thrown when you attempt to read from a stream that has no (more) characters to be read.
2. The getConsole() method is defined to return `null` when there is no interactive "console" available.

When you are executing an application from an "rc.local" script on a Raspberry Pi, that (presumably) happens *before* there is a console configured for you to read from.  That is most likely an OS limitation.  (There is a similar limitation in classic Linux systems, etc)

> What do I need to do, to read a keyboard input in rc.local?

I suspect that what you need to do is to have your "rc.local" script launch a virtual console and run the java application from that.